# Mathematical SUM of multiple rows by value

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table

```
user_name     id      status          calls
===========================================
apple        21       cars              67
apple        21       bikes             85
apple        21       skates            6
apple        21       pajs              56
orange       34       bikes             9
orange       34       disks             3
orange       34       cars              21
orange       34       pajs              76
```

I want to add up all the calls for `status's` that are cars, bikes and skates only and for each user_name. I have experminted with `SUM` but after several hours of late night, earnest attempts its pretty clear to me that this is going to require more than that. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

[My Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dc39)

Comment: You should show some of your failed attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select user_name, status, sum(calls) as calls
from table
where status in ('cars', 'bikes', 'skates')
group by user_name, status
```

Comment: any developer should know basic sql, as well as a ton on other things... :)

Comment: `SofianeM`: How is that a correlation? -- Also, it should be noted you can probably drop the `status` column from the select if you want them actually summed, otherwise you're going to get the sum of each   cars, type. (e.g. `apple` still has 67 cars, 85 bikes & 56 skates instead of 208 items)